# Thread with Smallrye Messaging

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, quarkus, smallrye, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I have a message consumer like this one in Quarkus that consume messages in a queue :

```
@Incoming("incoming-messages")
@Blocking(ordered = false, value = "custom-worker-pool")
public Uni<Void> onExecutionReceive(final Message<JsonObject> message) {
       message.ack();
       // Do long process here 
       
       return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
}
```

With associated configuration in application.properties :

```
smallrye.messaging.worker.custom-worker-pool.max-concurrency=3
```

This works well : A vertex worker thread consume my messages.
But the problem occurs when my blocking process exceed 60s i get this warning :

```
.. has been blocked for 61159 ms, time limit is 60000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
```

In order to avoid that i would replace the vertex worker thread used by smallrye by a regular thread pool that has no time limitation for example something like Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).

Is it possible to do so ?
If yes how ?

Comment: It's offtopi: but why would your process take longer than 60 seconds?

Comment: Well because it is a long-running job that is supposed to be triggered by a message

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `Uni`. You can do something like:

```java
@Incoming("incoming-messages")
@Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.MANUAL)
@Blocking(ordered = false, value = "custom-worker-pool")
public Uni<Void> onExecutionReceive(final Message<JsonObject> message) {
       return Uni.createFrom().emitter((UniEmitter<? super Object> uniEmitter) -> {
                    try {
                        // do long-running stuff here
                        uniEmitter.complete(new Object()); // Possibly some job result to return if needed
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        uniEmitter.fail(e);
                    }
                })
                .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool()) // worker pool can also be defined for subscription
                .onItem().invoke(message::ack)
                .onFailure().invoke(message::nack)
                .replaceWithVoid();
}
```

Possibly you can adapt it for your requirements (e.g play around with `emitter` some other form of creation of Uni)

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. When i add breakpoint on // do long-running stuff here it is never reached. Seems that try{...}catch{ ...} is simply never executed